# What is the output of an r-round Feistel network

Tags: feistel-network

What is the output of an r-round Feistel network when the input is (L0, R0) if Each round function is the identity function.

Comment: What did you try to solve the problem yourself? Look up a definition of Feistel Networks and just follow that with the identity function. What happens then in 1 round? Or 2 rounds?

Comment: When I tried there is a repetition of order for every 3 rounds. 1 round gives R0, L0 xor R0 .... and 3rd round gives L0 , R0. I wanted to know if there is any intuition from this?

Answer (score 1):

You already solved the question pretty much yourself. Let's take a look at the [general definition of a Feistel Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher#Construction_details):
$$ L_{i+1} = R_i, \quad R_{i+1} = L_i \oplus F(R_i, K_i) $$
With the identity function $F: (R_i, K_i) \mapsto R_i $ this now leads to a very insecure Feistel Cipher.

*Before round 1:*
$L_0,\quad R_0$

*After round 1:*
$L_1 = R_0,\quad R_1 = L_0 \oplus F(R_0, K_0) = L_0 \oplus R_0$

*After round 2:*
$L_2 = R_1 = L_0 \oplus R_0,\quad R_2 = L_1 \oplus F(R_1, K_1) = R_0 \oplus (L_0 \oplus R_0) = L_0$

*After round 3:*
$L_3 = R_2 = L_0,\quad R_3 = L_2 \oplus F(R_2, K_2) = (L_0 \oplus R_0) \oplus L_0 = R_0$

As you already figured out for yourself, the output of this Feistel Cipher has a period of three rounds. What do we now learn from that?

- The identity function is a terrible choice for $F$ as one can trivially crack the ciphertext with some known plaintext patterns.
- Different keys don't change the ciphertext at all, reducing the entropy of every key to 0.
- Adding more rounds doesn't necessarily increase the security of a Feistel Cipher. One or two rounds with this cipher is more secure than three rounds. This may be a contrived insight, but could be important for proves regarding Feistel Ciphers.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for 4 rounds, you can get the pattern and derive the solution for r-rounds yourself[image: ![4 rounds feistel]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGMuK.jpg)